# error: OpenCV(4.5.1) ../modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'

Tags: opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

I want to convert a raster image into NumPy array with (224, 224) dimensions before loading the VGG-16 neural network pre-trained on ImageNet. My code is raising `error: OpenCV(4.5.1) ../modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'` error even when the image could be successfully read from path.

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import sys
from keras.preprocessing import image as image_utils
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import decode_predictions
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
from keras.applications.resnet import ResNet50
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet121
import cv2

reg001_path = "../sample_data/mosaic/sample IDs A015-C-202 (Reg1) A001-C-002  (Reg2)_reg001.tif"
reg001 = gdal.Open(reg001_path)
channel_reg001 = np.array(reg001.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())

# Resize NumPy array to 224x224, the required input dimensions for the neural network
image = channel_reg001.resize((224, 224, 3))

# Expand the dimensions so we can pass it through the network
image = np.expand_dims(channel_reg001, axis=0)
# preprocess the image by subtracting the mean RGB pixel intensity from the ImageNet dataset
image = preprocess_input(image)

# load the VGG16 network pre-trained on the ImageNet dataset
print("[INFO] loading network...")
model = VGG16(weights="imagenet")
# classify the image
print("[INFO] classifying image...")
preds = model.predict(image)
P = decode_predictions(preds)
# loop over the predictions and display the rank-5 predictions +
# probabilities to our terminal
for (i, (imagenetID, label, prob)) in enumerate(P[0]):
    print("{}. {}: {:.2f}%".format(i + 1, label, prob * 100))
# load the image via OpenCV, draw the top prediction on the image,
# and display the image to our screen
orig = cv2.imread(r"reg001_path")
(imagenetID, label, prob) = P[0][0]
cv2.putText(orig, "Label: {}, {:.2f}%".format(label, prob * 100), (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow("Classification", orig)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Traceback:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- error                                     Traceback (most recent call
> last) /tmp/ipykernel_7165/3707729371.py in <module>
>      15 (imagenetID, label, prob) = P[0][0]
>      16 cv2.putText(orig, "Label: {}, {:.2f}%".format(label, prob * 100), (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 255, 0), 2)
> ---> 17 cv2.imshow("Classification", orig)
>      18 cv2.waitKey(0)
>      19 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
> 
> error: OpenCV(4.5.1) ../modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:376: error:
> (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function
> 'imshow'
```

The image could be successfully read:

```
img = cv2.imread("../sample_data/mosaic/sample IDs A015-C-202 (Reg1) A001-C-002  (Reg2)_reg001.tif" ,0)
print(img)
[[  0   1  24 ...   2  40  25]
 [ 71   2  22 ...   3  23  58]
 [ 82   3  38 ... 147 116   3]
 ...
 [  0   0   0 ...  14   1   0]
 [183  31   0 ...  50  34   0]
 [119   3   8 ...   1  11   3]]
```

Comment: no, the image **couldn't** be read successfully. the code that throws the error is *different* from the code you claim proves otherwise. `orig` is None. look and you will see. `putText` *doesn't* throw an error with img being None. I just checked that.

Comment: So what should I do? How can I edit the code?

Comment: I changed to `orig = cv2.imread(reg001_path)`, which is not empty. But it still throw the error.

Answer (score -1):

> The image could be successfully read:

> `img = cv2.imread("../sample_data/mosaic/sample IDs A015-C-202 (Reg1) A001-C-002  (Reg2)_reg001.tif" ,0)`

> `reg001_path = "../sample_data/mosaic/sample IDs A015-C-202 (Reg1) A001-C-002  (Reg2)_reg001.tif"`

if so, you probably wanted to load your `orig` image like:

```
orig = cv2.imread(reg001_path) # loading the *value* of 'reg001_path'
```

not like:

```
orig = cv2.imread(r"reg001_path") # loading the *name* of 'reg001_path'
```

however, please make it a habit to **always check** the result of imread() before continuing calculations, as it will return `None` silently on failure, not throw an exception

last, i'd consider `putText()` accepting invalid images silently an opencv bug !